# Calculating standard deviation in with svyfgt (R)

Tags: r, survey, standard-deviation, standard-error

I am using t-tests in R to test the significance of the difference in means that arises when adding weights, stratification, and clustering (respectively) to the survey design when utilizing the FGT measure of poverty, which I calculate using the svyfgt function in the convey package. I am running the t-tests by creating vectors for each survey design which include the mean, standard deviation, and sample size, hence, I need to obtain the standard deviation for the svyfgt mean.

In the survey package, there is a svysd function, which is used to calculate the standard deviation when complex survey designs are applied. This value is quite different from the value obtained by simply multiplying the SE by sqrt(n), as shown below:

```
library(survey)

wel <- c(68008.19, 128504.61,  21347.69,
             33272.95,  61828.96,  32764.44,
             92545.62,  58431.89,  95596.82,
             117734.27)
rmul <- c(16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16,
              20, 20, 20)
splin <- c(23149.64, 23149.64, 23149.64, 23149.64, 23149.64,
            21322.23, 21322.23, 21322.23, 21322.23, 21322.23)

survey.data <- data.frame(wel, rmul, splin)

survey_weighted <- svydesign(data = survey.data,
                             ids = ~wel, 
                             weights = ~rmul, 
                             nest = TRUE)

svymean(~wel, survey_weighted)

svysd(~wel, survey_weighted)
11498*sqrt(10)
```

In the convey package, there is no equivalent "svyfgtsd" function, and simply multiplying the SE by sqrt(n) would seem to yield the wrong answer (based on the previously shown difference in results between svysd and that expression). Therefore, I am not sure how I might obtain the standard deviation for FGT_0_weighted. Is there a function I am not aware of, or a stats concept that might aid me here?

```
library(convey)

fgtsurvey_weighted <- convey_prep(survey_weighted) 

FGT_0_weighted <- svyfgt(~wel, 
                         fgtsurvey_weighted,  
                         g=0, 
                         abs_thresh = survey.data$splin)
FGT_0_weighted
```

For reference, I will be using the sd values in t-tests like so (disregard sd values):

```
FGT_0_unweighted_vector <- c(rnorm(9710, mean = 0.28919, sd = sd_FGT_0))
FGT_0_cluster_vector <- c(rnorm(9710, mean = 0.33259, sd = sd_FGT_0_cluster))
t.test(FGT_0_cluster_vector, FGT_0_unweighted_vector, var.equal = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the poverty threshold is absolute, the FGT is the mean of a binary variable (poor/non-poor); i.e., a proportion. The *standard deviation* of a binary variable is `sqrt( p*(1-p) )`.

However, you are probably looking for the *standard error* (a measure of the sampling error of the FGT estimate), just do `SE( FGT_0_weighted )`. That's what is used in t-tests.

Taking stratification and clustering into account will alter standard error estimates, while weighting will affect the mean (and all point estimates, like FGT) as well. Using t-tests to test whether mean estimates change makes sense for comparing weighted and unweighted estimates.

Working with `sqrt(n)` is misleading under complex sampling. The usual `n` is what is called *nominal* sample size, but the *effective* sample size is usually smaller than that (because of cluster sampling.).

A concept related to what you are tying to do is the design effect, but that is not yet implemented for `svyfgt` (although, for absolute thresholds, you can still get it using `svymean`).

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer, your book on this subject has been an essential reference to me in my current project. The standard error is easy enough to retrieve in convey, however I was under the impression that when conducting a t-test using rnorm() (rather than just referencing data), I needed to plug in standard deviation (and n, which I now know is nominal), eg: c(rnorm(n, mean = ?, sd = ?)). Is there a statistical justification for using SE instead? For reference, I learned how to t-test in this manner on this page: https://datascienceplus.com/t-tests/

Comment: It turns out you are using the standard-error for that:`sd/sqrt(n)` is the standard-error of the mean under simple random sampling with replacement.

There is also another thing: svyfgt takes a single value as the absolute poverty line; that wont work. But this will: `svymean(~I( wel < splin ), survey_weighted )`

Comment: This is insightful, but I would like clarification on both points: (1)  I thought that using `S.E.*sqrt(n)` would not work because of the difference between "nominal n" and "effective n."  [For weighted sampling, the result from`svysd()` is not equal to `SE*sqrt(n)`]. How then should I set up a t-test between unweighted and weighted FGT? (2) The result from the `svymean()` code you provided in your comment is equal to each `svyfgt()` result, despite a poverty threshold which is not constant across rows. Is there a reason that you are saying svyfgt will not work, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @nate You might have misunderstood the construction of simulated examples in https://datascienceplus.com/t-tests/ for the actual method of testing. To test the difference between two samples `a` and `b`  you can use`t.test(a, b, ...)` or calculate a t-value directly from the mean and standard error. Datascienceplus uses a fictional standard deviation to construct fictional samples with `rnorm`. To test real data, you do not need to create a simulated sample but can rather use the original data.

Comment: I agree in principle, however, in either the survey or convey package, I am not sure how to get to this "original data," as I am testing on the mean obtained from complex sampling methods. I could theoretically scrap the R functions and write out the formulas myself, but then I am left with the problem of nominal vs. effective sample size. I might be way off base, or misunderstanding something fundamental to the problem, but I still do not see a way forward in testing the equality of two means obtained from separate sampling methods (but same original data).

Comment: By changing `svydesign` with the same sample, you are not changing the sample design: you are changing the estimators. The sample design is the method by how the sample was selected from the finite population. If you are using SRS estimators for a cluster sample, you are "mispecifying" the sample design: you will (generally) have wrong results.

This article might be helpful: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1475-4991.1998.tb00254.x